# How to get two queries joined. Subqueries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, union

I can get it to work in two seperate queries but not in one. Can someone help me out please? I need the output something like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    PARENT_AK    |   PARENT_RK   |PARENT_RESOURCE_NAME|  C_RESOURCE_NAME   |   C_AK    |   C_RK      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    CONTAINER    | LOB           |SYSTEMROLE          | DEV                |CONTAINER  |LOB Options  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    CONTAINER    | LOB           |SYSTEMROLE          | PRODUCTION         |CONTAINER  |LOB Options  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    CONTAINER    | LOB           |SYSTEMROLE          | TEST               |CONTAINER  |LOB Options  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    CONTAINER    | LOB           |SYSTEMROLE          | UAT                |CONTAINER  |LOB Options  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    CONTAINER    | LOB           |SERVER_FUNCTION     | APPLICATION SERVER |CONTAINER  |LOB Options  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    CONTAINER    | LOB           |SERVER_FUNCTION     | DATABASE SERVER    |CONTAINER  |LOB Options  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    CONTAINER    | LOB           |SERVER_FUNCTION     | WEB SERVER         |CONTAINER  |LOB Options  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Query 1:

```
select 
'CONTAINER' as PARENT_AK, 
'LOB' as PARENT_RK, 
'SYSTEMROLE' as PARENT_RESOURCE_NAME, 
SYSTEMROLE as C_RESOURCE_NAME, 
'CONTAINER' as C_AK, 
'LOB Options' as C_RK
FROM CMDB
GROUP by C_RESOURCE_NAME;
```

Query 2:

```
select
'CONTAINER' as PARENT_AK, 
'LOB' as PARENT_RK, 
'SERVER_FUNCTION' as PARENT_RESOURCE_NAME, 
SERVER_FUNCTION as C_RESOURCE_NAME, 
'CONTAINER' as C_AK, 
'LOB Options' as C_RK
FROM CMDB
GROUP by C_RESOURCE_NAME;
```

Table (CMDB):

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|    NAME    |   SYSTEMROLE   |  SERVER_FUNCTION  |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|    Server1 |    Test        |APPLICATION SERVER |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|    Server2 |    PRODUCTION  |APPLICATION SERVER |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|    Server3 |    UAT         |DATABASE SERVER    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|    Server4 |    DEV         |WEB SERVER         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|    Server5 |    DEV         |WEB SERVER         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08e6a/12

Comment: Which is it, SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to UNPIVOT your table, but as far as I know MySQL does not have built-in UNPIVOT functionality. Therefore you will have to resort to what you are doing. Note though you can use a union to make a single request to the server as opposed to two ([SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08e6a/14)):

```
select 
'CONTAINER' as PARENT_AK, 
'LOB' as PARENT_RK, 
'SYSTEMROLE' as PARENT_RESOURCE_NAME, 
SYSTEMROLE as C_RESOURCE_NAME, 
'CONTAINER' as C_AK, 
'LOB Options' as C_RK
FROM CMDB
GROUP by C_RESOURCE_NAME;

UNION ALL

select
'CONTAINER' as PARENT_AK, 
'LOB' as PARENT_RK, 
'SERVER_FUNCTION' as PARENT_RESOURCE_NAME, 
SERVER_FUNCTION as C_RESOURCE_NAME, 
'CONTAINER' as C_AK, 
'LOB Options' as C_RK
FROM CMDB
GROUP by C_RESOURCE_NAME;
```

---

If instead you are using SQL Server 2008, as you note in your comments, you can use UNPIVOT to get your results:

```
select
  'CONTAINER' as PARENT_AK, 
  'LOB' as PARENT_RK, 
  PARENT_RESOURCE_NAME, C_RESOURCE_NAME,
  'CONTAINER' as C_AK, 
  'LOB Options' as C_RK
FROM
(
  SELECT CI_NAME, SYSTEMROLE, SERVER_FUNCTION
  FROM CMDB
) x
UNPIVOT
(
  C_RESOURCE_NAME FOR PARENT_RESOURCE_NAME IN (SYSTEMROLE, SERVER_FUNCTION)
) p
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08e6a/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION statement in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

```
SELECT
'CONTAINER' as PARENT_AK, 
'LOB' as PARENT_RK, 
'SYSTEMROLE' as PARENT_RESOURCE_NAME, 
SYSTEMROLE as C_RESOURCE_NAME, 
'CONTAINER' as C_AK, 
'LOB Options' as C_RK
FROM CMDB
GROUP by C_RESOURCE_NAME
UNION SELECT
'CONTAINER' as PARENT_AK, 
'LOB' as PARENT_RK, 
'SERVER_FUNCTION' as PARENT_RESOURCE_NAME, 
SERVER_FUNCTION as C_RESOURCE_NAME, 
'CONTAINER' as C_AK, 
'LOB Options' as C_RK
FROM CMDB
GROUP by C_RESOURCE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements using UNION.

Note : each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order

this like will help you more.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

```
SELECT
'CONTAINER' AS PARENT_AK, 
'LOB' AS PARENT_RK, 
'SYSTEMROLE' AS PARENT_RESOURCE_NAME, 
SYSTEMROLE AS C_RESOURCE_NAME, 
'CONTAINER' AS C_AK, 
'LOB Options' AS C_RK
FROM CMDB
GROUP BY C_RESOURCE_NAME

UNION

SELECT
'CONTAINER' AS PARENT_AK, 
'LOB' AS PARENT_RK, 
'SERVER_FUNCTION' AS PARENT_RESOURCE_NAME, 
SERVER_FUNCTION AS C_RESOURCE_NAME, 
'CONTAINER' AS C_AK, 
'LOB Options' AS C_RK
FROM CMDB
GROUP BY C_RESOURCE_NAME
```